# Acumatica - Users are receiving "Session Expired"

Tags: erp, acumatica

Web Users are receiving "Session Expired" when using Acumatica ERP, I have made the following changes to the Web Config file as per documentation:

- changed the ReminderRequestPeriod
- report Time-out settings
- Query Time-out settings

Answer (score 2):

Depending on when/where the users are receiving the timeouts it could be various items.

If the timeout is happening at a consistent duration, then chances are the users are hitting the standard ASP "Session" timeout.

In the web.config file look for the "sessionState" tag and see what the value in "timeout" is.  This is in minutes.  Increasing this value can increase the amount of time before a users "session" times out.

When modifying this value, you should also look to the "forms..." tag and see what the "timeout" there is set to.  This is the duration of the forms authentication duration.  These should match or be close or you'll have the authentication timing out before the actual session does.

If you are having random issues (timeouts occurring at various times to various users or multiple users at the same time), one thing to look at is the Eventlog on the server.  If there is a problem where the IIS Application pool is recycling (does this by default) or if it is crashing, the end user sessions are not persisted and will show the timeout message.

If it's a recycling issue, you can adjust the the amount of time before it recycles in the Application Pool.

If it's an issue with the pool crashing, there will be an event log showing the crash to help isolate where this is occurring.   I had a customer who had this issue recently.  After applying some updates they never restarted the server which was causing periodic application pool crashes.  Running low/out of memory can do this as well.

These won't guarantee a fix however it might help you isolate the cause of the timeouts

Comment: should your answer for what to look for in the web.config be teh formsAuth timeout value?

Comment: Updated the answer. the form tags were removing it.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar issue. In my case it worked increasing available memory at web server

Answer (score 0):

Also, remember that if your site was upgraded, you may need to reset your license keys. (you will probably need to contact Acumatica to do this) 
We have had clients where their license became invalid after upgrading to a newer version and then only 2 users could log in and if a 3rd user logged in one of the other users received the "Session Timeout" error.